# how to implement custom metric in keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, metrics

I get this error :

> sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'out'

when I run this code:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import keras
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential

def AUC(y_true,y_pred):
    not_y_pred=np.logical_not(y_pred)
    y_int1=y_true*y_pred
    y_int0=np.logical_not(y_true)*not_y_pred
    TP=np.sum(y_pred*y_int1)
    FP=np.sum(y_pred)-TP
    TN=np.sum(not_y_pred*y_int0)
    FN=np.sum(not_y_pred)-TN
    TPR=np.float(TP)/(TP+FN)
    FPR=np.float(FP)/(FP+TN)
    return((1+TPR-FPR)/2)

# Input datasets

train_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(91,1000))
train_df.iloc[:,-2]=(train_df.iloc[:,-2]>0.8)*1


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(output_dim=60, input_dim=91, init="glorot_uniform"))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.add(Dense(output_dim=1, input_dim=60, init="glorot_uniform"))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=[AUC])


train_df.iloc[:,-1]=np.ones(train_df.shape[0]) #bias
X=train_df.iloc[:,:-1].values
Y=train_df.iloc[:,-1].values
print X.shape,Y.shape

model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=50,show_accuracy = False, verbose = 1)
```

Is it possible to implement a custom metric aside from doing a loop on batches and editing the source code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that `y_pred` and `y_true` are not NumPy arrays but either Theano or TensorFlow tensors. That's why you got this error.

You can define your custom metrics but you have to remember that its arguments are those tensors – not NumPy arrays.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate how to solve this? How can I transform a Tensor to a numpy array?

Comment: You need to think about a tensor as an algebraic variable. You cannot transform numpy array to tensor. You could only assign the numpy array as a value of a tensor.

Comment: I don't want to transform a numpy array to a tensor but the other way around. If we take OP's function, I tried: `def AUC(y_true,y_pred): numpy_y_true = y_true.eval() ... return ...` but it didn't work. How would you solve OP's problem?

Comment: A custom metric can't be a typical number-returning function.  Even "def auc(y_true, y_pred): return 1.0" won't work.  The metric function gets called at compile time once, before any training examples are seen.

Comment: That's true. But still inputs need to be tensors

Answer (score 67):

Here I'm answering to OP's topic question rather than his exact problem. I'm doing this as the question shows up in the top when I google the topic problem.

You can implement a custom metric in two ways.

1. As mentioned in [Keras docu](https://keras.io/metrics#custom-metrics).

   ```
   import keras.backend as K

   def mean_pred(y_true, y_pred):
       return K.mean(y_pred)

   model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
             loss='binary_crossentropy',
             metrics=['accuracy', mean_pred])
   ```

   But here you have to remember as mentioned in Marcin Możejko's answer that `y_true` and `y_pred` are tensors. So in order to correctly calculate the metric you need to use `keras.backend` functionality. Please look at this SO question for details [How to calculate F1 Macro in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547402/how-to-calculate-f1-macro-in-keras)
2. Or you can implement it in a hacky way as mentioned in [Keras GH issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5794#issuecomment-303683985). For that you need to use `callbacks` argument of `model.fit`.

   ```
   import keras as keras
   import numpy as np
   from keras.optimizers import SGD
   from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

   model = keras.models.Sequential()
   # ...
   sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
   model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


   class Metrics(keras.callbacks.Callback):
       def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
           self._data = []

       def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
           X_val, y_val = self.validation_data[0], self.validation_data[1]
           y_predict = np.asarray(model.predict(X_val))

           y_val = np.argmax(y_val, axis=1)
           y_predict = np.argmax(y_predict, axis=1)

           self._data.append({
               'val_rocauc': roc_auc_score(y_val, y_predict),
           })
           return

       def get_data(self):
           return self._data

   metrics = Metrics()
   history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), callbacks=[metrics])
   metrics.get_data()
   ```

Comment: I suggest  using self.model rather than model so that this class can be stashed away at a different file.

Comment: @For people working with large validation dataset, you will face twice the validation time. One validation done by keras and one done by your metrics by calling predict. Another issue is now your metrics uses GPU to do predict and cpu to compute metrics using numpy, thus GPU and CPU are in serial. If metric is compute expensive, you will face worse GPU utilization and will have to do optimization that are already done in keras.

Comment: @saurabheights any workarounds for this then using callbacks

Comment: I don't think the validation_data will be passed to the `on_epoch_end` method when I use this code, it says `None type not subscriptable`

Comment: @LikithReddy Sorry, but I dont even remember my above comment well. Used Keras quite a lot in my last company but havent used Keras in over a year. Plus, I no longer have the keras setup locally, so it will be a few hours work, to dig in and see what u r asking. ATM, I wont be able to help, too busy. If I can recall, what I did was do double GPU predict call. Validation is quite fast so GPU wasnt problem. I moved CPU computation code to another process(using futures, queue...).

Comment: This way, serial code would not block GPU code. Got quite high speed improvements. Plus during validation, u can use higher batch size(no gpu memory used in validation/inference), so validation runs quite fast.

Comment: This technique works well. Hint: Use `y_predict = np.asarray(model.predict(X_val, batch_size=32768))` to drop prediction time, in my  case it went from 14 seconds to 0.40 seconds.

Comment: FYI, I am getting `AttributeError: ... object has no attribute 'validation_data'` when I go for the option with `Callback`.

Answer (score 4):

you can pass a model.predict() in your AUC metric function. [this will iterate on bacthes so you might be better off using model.predict_on_batch(). Assuming you have something like a softmax layer as output (something that outputs probabilities), then you can use that together with sklearn.metric to get the AUC.

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
```

from [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-roc-py)

```
def sklearnAUC(test_labels,test_prediction):
    n_classes = 2
    # Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
    fpr = dict()
    tpr = dict()
    roc_auc = dict()
    for i in range(n_classes):
        # ( actual labels, predicted probabilities )
        fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(test_labels[:, i], test_prediction[:, i])
        roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

    return round(roc_auc[0],3) , round(roc_auc[1],3)
```

now make your metric

```
# gives a numpy array like so [ [0.3,0.7] , [0.2,0.8] ....]    
Y_pred = model.predict_on_batch ( X_test  ) 
# Y_test looks something like [ [0,1] , [1,0] .... ]
# auc1 and auc2 should be equal
auc1 , auc2 = sklearnAUC(  Y_test ,  Y_pred )
```