# How can i reshape a one dimension array into a two dimension?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, nlp

I want to calculate and print `roc_auc_score` to evaluate the performance of my random forest model. I am doing NLP, hence the data in `y_test` and `y_pred` are  list of words, I vectorize them with the function `pipe_vect.transform`, but when I print `y_test` and `y_pred`, they don't have the same dimension, here what I get:

```
print('y_pred dimension: ', y_pred.shape) #y_pred dimension:  (417, 1)
print('y_test dimension: ', y_test.shape) #y_test dimension:  (417,)
```

Therefore, I want to reshape `y_test` and give it two dimension.

Here my code :

```
x_test_vect = pipe_vect.transform(x_test)
y_pred = model.predict_proba(x_test_vect)
auc_score = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)
print('Performance du modèle :', auc_score)
```

which yields the following error:

> ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case.

Comment: `y_test[:, np.newaxis]` should work

Comment: you can reshape your `y_pred` with `y_pred.reshape(-1)`

Comment: what different value are there in y_test?????

Comment: The error is not due to the dimensions but because `y_true` is either all 1s or all 0s

Comment: @FBruzzesi do you know how can i fix this error ?

Comment: Assuming that you actually have different labels in `y`, if you split the data using sklearn `train_test_split` provide the parameter `stratify=y`, if you split the data in some other manner it depends.

Comment: Pleas read closely the error message; as @FBruzzesi notices, it is due to one of your classes **not** being present in your test data `y_true`. You don't have a reshaping issue, and your description led to the question been erroneously closed as a duplicate. Check your `y_test`, as well as the exact way you are producing them (which you do not show).

Answer (score 2):

You can add dim using [`numpy.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html#numpy-expand-dims)

```py
y_test = np.random.randn(417)
y_test.shape
(417,)

y_test = np.expand_dims(a, axis=1)
y_test.shape
(417, 1)
```

Comment: thanks ! but when i want to calculate and print the roc_auc_score function, i have always this error : ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case

Comment: Check this it may help - https://stackoverflow.com/q/45139163/6075699

Answer (score 1):

To add a dimension to y_test:

```
y_test.shape # (417,)
y_test = y_test[...,np.newaxis]
y_test.shape # (417,1)
```

To remove a dimenstion from y_pred:

```
y_pred.shape # (417,1)
y_pred = y_pred.flatten()
y_pred.shape # (417,)
```

Comment: it works thanks ! but when i want to calculate and print the roc_auc_score function, i have always this error : ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case.

Comment: As a best practice, if you only have a dimension 1 to remove, I think you should use `y_pred.squeeze()` as it is way faster.