# Keras custom matric: ROC curve

Tags: keras

I am using custom matric as given on keras website:

```python
def compute_roc (y_true, y_pred):
    y_true =K.eval(y_true)#.eval(session=sess)
    y_pred = K.eval(y_pred)#.eval(session=sess)
    roc = metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_pred, pos_label=2)
    roc = tf.to_float(roc, name='ToFloat')
    return roc
```

But I am getting error on "K.eval(y_true)"

> ```python
>     InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-7-1de7569967ec> in <module>()
>      20 #disc.load_weights(os.path.join(path, model_name+'.h5'))
>      21 sgd = SGD(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
> ---> 22 disc.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=sgd,metrics=['accuracy',
> ```
>
> compute_roc])
>            23 #plot_model(model, to_file='model.png')
>            24 print('disc model loaded')
>
> ```python
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in compile(self, optimizer, loss, metrics, loss_weights,
> ```
>
> sample_weight_mode, weighted_metrics, target_tensors, **kwargs)
>           912                         append_metric(i, metric_name, metric_result)
>           913 
>       --> 914                 handle_metrics(output_metrics)
>           915                 handle_metrics(output_weighted_metrics, weights=weights)
>           916
>
> ```python
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in handle_metrics(metrics, weights)
>     909                             metric_result = weighted_metric_fn(y_true, y_pred,
>     910                                                                weights=weights,
> --> 911                                                                mask=masks[i])
>     912                         append_metric(i, metric_name, metric_result)
>     913 
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.pyc in weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask)
>     424         """
>     425         # score_array has ndim >= 2
> --> 426         score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
>     427         if mask is not None:
>     428             # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in theano
>
> <ipython-input-7-1de7569967ec> in compute_roc(y_true, y_pred)
>       4 
>       5 def compute_roc (y_true, y_pred):
> ----> 6     y_true1 =K.eval(y_true)#.eval(session=sess)
>       7    # y_pred1 = K.eval(y_pred)#.eval(session=sess)
>       8     roc = 0#metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_pred, pos_label=2)
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.pyc
> ```
>
> in eval(x)
>           658     ```
>           659     """
>       --> 660     return to_dense(x).eval(session=get_session())
>           661 
>           662
>
> ```python
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc
> ```
>
> in eval(self, feed_dict, session)
>           539 
>           540     """
>       --> 541     return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
>           542 
>           543
>
> ```python
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.pyc
> ```
>
> in _eval_using_default_session(tensors, feed_dict, graph, session)
>          4083                        "the tensor's graph is different from the session's "
>          4084                        "graph.")
>       -> 4085   return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
>          4086 
>          4087
>
> ```python
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc
> ```
>
> in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>           893     try:
>           894       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
>       --> 895                          run_metadata_ptr)
>           896       if run_metadata:
>           897         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
>
> ```python
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc
> ```
>
> in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>          1122     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
>          1123       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
>       -> 1124                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
>          1125     else:
>          1126       results = []
>
> ```python
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc
> ```
>
> in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options,
>   run_metadata)
>          1319     if handle is None:
>          1320       return self._do_call(_run_fn, self._session, feeds, fetches, targets,
>       -> 1321                            options, run_metadata)
>          1322     else:
>          1323       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, self._session, handle, feeds, fetches)
>
> ```python
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc
> ```
>
> in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
>          1338         except KeyError:
>          1339           pass
>       -> 1340       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
>          1341 
>          1342   def _extend_graph(self):
>
> ```python
> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_6_target' with dtype float and shape [?,?]
>    [[Node: dense_6_target = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
>    [[Node: dense_6_target/_833 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
> ```
>
> send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4_dense_6_target",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
>
> ```python
> Caused by op u'dense_6_target', defined at:
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
>     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
>     exec code in run_globals
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line
> ```
>
> 16, in 
>           app.launch_new_instance()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py",
>   line 658, in launch_instance
>           app.start()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line
>   478, in start
>           self.io_loop.start()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line
>   177, in start
>           super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
>           handler_func(fd_obj, events)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py",
>   line 277, in null_wrapper
>           return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py",
>   line 440, in _handle_events
>           self._handle_recv()
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py",
>   line 472, in _handle_recv
>           self._run_callback(callback, msg)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py",
>   line 414, in _run_callback
>           callback(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py",
>   line 277, in null_wrapper
>           return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line
>   283, in dispatcher
>           return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line
>   233, in dispatch_shell
>           handler(stream, idents, msg)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line
>   399, in execute_request
>           user_expressions, allow_stdin)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line
>   208, in do_execute
>           res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line
>   537, in run_cell
>           return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2718, in run_cell
>           interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
>           if self.run_code(code, result):
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2882, in run_code
>           exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>         File "", line 22, in 
>           disc.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=sgd,metrics=['accuracy',
>   compute_roc])
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py",
>   line 722, in compile
>           dtype=K.dtype(self.outputs[i]))
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 504, in placeholder
>           x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py",
>   line 1548, in placeholder
>           return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py",
>   line 2094, in _placeholder
>           name=name)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py",
>   line 767, in apply_op
>           op_def=op_def)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 2630, in create_op
>           original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
>         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1204, in **init**
>           self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>
> ```python
> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'dense_6_target' with dtype float and
> ```
>
> shape [?,?]
>          [[Node: dense_6_target = Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]]
>          [[Node: dense_6_target/_833 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_4_dense_6_target",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

The other way is to compute "y_pred" at the end of each epoch and compute roc.

Comment: Why don't you use `sklearn roc_auc` after getting predictions from your model?

Comment: The problem is with: 
y_true =K.eval(y_true) AND
y_pred = K.eval(y_pred)

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. **Using ski learn function within custom `Callback` ( on-epoch_end).**

   In this case you need to get the `batch_x, batch_y` by passing your train generator to you callback, then calculate the `y_pred` ( on_batch_begin) through `model.predict(batch_x)`  then accumulate it at (on_epoch_end) callback and then calculate the `AUC` using your function.
2. **Building custom metric in Keras using tf.meteric auc**

   AUC, update_op = tf.metric.auc(y_true, y_pred)

In this case you don't need to calculate the y_pred for each batch. just build custom metric function and pass it to callback. You need to ensure to update the ( update_op) for each batch because Auc metric need to be calculated at the end of epoch not on batch level.

you can also look the comment of Tom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032551/how-to-compute-receiving-operating-characteristic-roc-and-auc-in-keras) where you can find sample code for the above suggestion. However they refer to tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc which is deprecated and replaced by tf.metric.auc