# Why does the AUROC of the validation set differ between training and subsequent evaluation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Given the following minimal example:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam import Adam

negatives = np.random.beta(0.6, 1.2, 100)
positives = np.random.beta(1.7, 0.9, 100)

x = np.concatenate((negatives, positives))
y = np.concatenate((np.full(negatives.size, 0), np.full(positives.size, 1)))

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape=(1,), activation="sigmoid"))
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.1),
              loss="binary_crossentropy",
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(curve="ROC", name="AUROC")])

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=100, verbose=True, batch_size=10000))

auroc_val = tf.keras.metrics.AUC(curve="ROC", name="AUROC")(y_test, model.predict(x_test).flatten()).numpy()
print(f"{auroc_val=}")
```

I'd expect `auroc_val` to be equal to `val_AUROC` (from the last training epoch). However, in reality, it is not.

Output of one run:

```
...
Epoch 98/100
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.5247 - AUROC: 0.8144 - val_loss: 0.5277 - val_AUROC: 0.8143
Epoch 99/100
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.5242 - AUROC: 0.8143 - val_loss: 0.5290 - val_AUROC: 0.8144
Epoch 100/100
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.5250 - AUROC: 0.8145 - val_loss: 0.5264 - val_AUROC: 0.8145
auroc_val=0.83203566
```

Output of another run:

```
...
Epoch 100/100
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.4771 - AUROC: 0.8055 - val_loss: 0.6642 - val_AUROC: 0.8054
auroc_val=0.7224694
```

Why is this?

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291804/keras-different-validation-auroc-during-training-and-on-epoch-end), because I'm using a batch size larger than the sample size. Thus, `val_AUROC` should be calculated over the whole validation set at the end of each epoch.

Comment: I could not replicate your error, for me the values are the same. But I had to delete the `from tensorflow.python..` imports and create e.g. the Dense layer with `tf.keras.layers.Dense`. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/61215#issuecomment-1628600138 for details. My TF version is 2.13.0 (which would explain the `tf.keras.python` import error), python 3.10.11. Please try without the imports mentioned above and check your TF version.

Comment: @mhenning Oh, thanks a lot! I [applied your suggestions](https://gist.github.com/Dobiasd/26dc8f1d5338eeb4d96dad60da01b895), and now `auroc_val` is always equal to `val_AUROC` for me too. Would you like to post your solution as an answer to the question, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not replicate your error, for me the values are the same. But I had to delete the `from tensorflow.python..` imports and create e.g. the Dense layer with `tf.keras.layers.Dense`. See [this explanation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/61215#issuecomment-1628600138) for details on why not to use `tensorflow.python`.
My TF version is 2.13.0 (which would explain the `tf.python.keras` import error), python 3.10.11. Please try without the imports mentioned above and check your TF version.
(This answer was originally only the comment under the question.)