# changes in training metrics after changing label encoding

Tags: python, tensorflow, encoding, keras

I am training a binary classifier using Keras.

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=[auroc,'accuracy'])
```

I use a custom metric, AUROC.[as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032551/how-to-compute-receiving-operating-characteristic-roc-and-auc-in-keras)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score  
def auroc(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.py_func(roc_auc_score, (y_true, y_pred), tf.double)
```

So far, I have encoded my target as one-hot encoding 
and I had a last layer as

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y = to_categorical(y)
[...]
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I have learned that in principle here [Keras binary_crossentropy vs categorical_crossentropy performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42081257/keras-binary-crossentropy-vs-categorical-crossentropy-performance)I should not perform categorical encoding, and I should predict only one class using

```
# y = to_categorical(y)
[...]
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

However, if I apply this and only this change my training `auroc` changes dramatically, from high 0.90s to 0.50. Even more strangely, `val_auroc` loss seems unaffected

How did that happen?

Comment: The most important question is: What type of label are you trying to predict? If you only have 2 classes, positive and negative, then binary should be used rather than categorical (as in [this](https://gombru.github.io/2018/05/23/cross_entropy_loss/) very good post), because binary is a special case of categorical with its own formula that assume only a pos/neg class

Comment: it is indeed binary.that's why I have removed the categorical encoding. this motivates the rest of a question. why that caused some much changes?is it expected?

Comment: If you removed the categorical encoding, I'm assuming you also removed the one-hot encoding of your labels as It shouldn't be necessary. Regarding your training AUROC score, remember that if the area under your ROC curve is ~0.5, your model is unable to do any better than pure random guessing. Given this, are you sure that your `val_auroc` loss is being recalculated and not just re-used from an earlier run?