# ValueError: Unknown metric function:binary_precision error in Keras even when not using any custom metric

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I trained a cnn model with `precision` and `recall` metrics which are imported from `keras_metrics`. But when I tried to load the model, I am getting the error: `ValueError: Unknown metric function:binary_precision`. I have not used `binary_precision` function anywhere but still I gave `binary_precision' in custom_objects as per the error:

```
 model = load_model(modelfilepath,custom_objects={'metrics': [keras_metrics.precision(),binary_precision]})
```

With this I am getting the error, `NameError: name 'binary_precision' is not defined`. What should I do for this.

My code is as follows:

```
#compiling the model
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(),loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics = ['accuracy',keras_metrics.precision(),keras_metrics.recall()])
#loading the model after training and saving it
model = load_model(modelfilepath,custom_objects={'metrics': [keras_metrics.precision(),binary_precision]})
```

Comment: Did you forget the brackets? `binary_precision()`. Moreover, I think `binary_precision` is also located in the keras_metrics package, so you'd have to write `keras_metrics.binary_precision()`

Comment: @JuliaK, I tried that as well, but still the same issue

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution in https://github.com/netrack/keras-metrics/issues/27: the author add **name** attribute in the module, so we can call metrics function by its name when loading model:

```
import keras_metrics as km

# compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='Adam',metrics=['acc', km.binary_precision(), km.binary_recall()])

# load model
model = load_model(os.path.join(FLAGS.init_checkpoint,model_name), custom_objects={'binary_precision':km.binary_precision(), 'binary_recall':km.binary_recall()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try simply loading the model without custom objects. In your case, it seems you are using KEras defined metrics only and no custom metrics. That may be the reason you it is not able to find the function. If still not resolved, please share the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Tensorflow and Keras package to new versions.

```
1. pip install --upgrade tensorflow 
2. pip install --upgrade keras
```

Check this link for using Keras inbuilt - Metrics for precision, recall, AUC etc.

> [How to compute Receiving Operating Characteristic (ROC) and AUC in keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032551/how-to-compute-receiving-operating-characteristic-roc-and-auc-in-keras/59652792#59652792)