# How can I define custom geometric mean evaluation metrics in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, imblearn

How can implement the following imblearn geometric mean in Tensorflow to compile LSTM model?

```
from imblearn.metrics import geometric_mean_score
gmean = geometric_mean_score(yTest,yPred)
```

I wanted to use the following option, but it is not working like `metrics=[keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc')]`

```
from keras import backend 
def gmean(y_true, y_pred):
    return backend.geometric_mean_score(yTest,yPred)
```

I tried this [Available StackOverflow suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63028477/problem-defining-a-custom-metric-to-calculate-geometric-mean-score-for-tensor) , but it didn't work as well.